# Special kind of specie in Spore?

Tags: spore

I was playing Spore and found some kind of special specie, as it had 999 HP and was really big compared to others, also it was pretty aggressive towards everything near it including my specie.

It lived near the ‘border’ and I couldn’t interact with it in a friendly way.

**What is it? And why is it there?**

Answer (score 2):

That's an [epic creature](http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Epic_creature), a huge variant of regular creatures. It exists to be an obstacle and can't be befriended.

Comment: I didn’t know it was called an ‘Epic Creature’. Thank you!